# only run azure pipeline template if previous step succeeded

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there a way to run a template if and only if the previous step in the pipeline job completed successfully and anther condition is met as well?  Here's what I tried:

```
- ${{ if and(in(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues'), eq(parameters.deployToDevServer, true)) }}:
  - template: Templates/push-files-to-release-artifacts-repo.yml
    parameters:
      releaseArtifactsRepoPath: $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/ReleaseArtifacts
```

But the step doesn't execute at all.  I also tried using the `succeeded()` conditional but it wouldn't validate the YAML.  To sum it up, I am trying to conditionally run this template based on whether the parameters.deployToDevServer value is true **and** the previous step succeeded.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `true` literal into single quotes? Also, the `:` at the end of the condition line is just a typo, right?
I mean it might look like:
`${{ if and(in(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues'), eq(parameters.deployToDevServer, 'true')) }}`
If still no luck, I would suggest running a dummy step just to output the values of the variables that participate in the condition.

Comment: The colon is necessary, I'm using the syntax documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-192-update#new-yaml-conditional-expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible to do this in this way. Because you are mixing compile-time (`${{ }}`) and run-time (`variables['Agent.JobStatus']`) expressions here `- ${{ if and(in(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues'), eq(parameters.deployToDevServer, true)) }}:`

The whole expression is evaluated at compile and then `variables['Agent.JobStatus']` is just empty. You need to use conditions to skip your stage/job/step in your template. But it has to be done in the template.